# Android: ksoap2 request remove namespace from tags

Tags: android, ksoap

I am using KSOAP which has created the following Request payload: -

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <v:Header/>
   <v:Body>
      <n0:ZmobileExecuteReport id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
         <Function>EXE</Function>
         <Parameters i:type="n0:Parameters">
            <n0:item>
               <Selname>P_AUART</Selname>
               <Kind>P</Kind>
               <Sign>I</Sign>
               <Option>EQ</Option>
               <Low>Z1</Low>
               <High>Z2</High>
            </n0:item>
         </Parameters>
         <Repid>ZSIMPLE_REPORT0</Repid>
      </n0:ZmobileExecuteReport>
   </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

The webservice that this is being passed into will only work if the value for the element "item" is  and not

I have used the statement envelope.implicitTypes = true; which has supressed the "type" attribute being defined, but I am still having this issue.

Has anybody had this issue before and been able to resolve it.

I am using KSOAP2 2.5.8 version.

This is how I build the request: -

```
SoapObject parameters = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Parameters");
SoapObject item = new SoapObject("NAMESPAC", "item");

item.addProperty("Selname", "P_AUART");
item.addProperty("Kind", "P");
item.addProperty("Sign", "I");
item.addProperty("Option", "EQ");
item.addProperty("Low", "A1");
item.addProperty("High", "A2");

parameters.addSoapObject(item);
```

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by doing this: -

```
SoapObject parameters = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Parameters");
SoapObject item = new SoapObject("", "item");
```

Removing the NAMESPACE from the child node fixed it.

I should have also mentioned it was when I was calling a webservice on a SAP ABAP Stack.